# ionic camera plugin app gets refreshed after taking image

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using the cordova-plugin-camera to capture image using phone camera . I have a button in my html page as below

```
   <a class="item item-thumbnail-left" href="#">
            <img src="img/preview.png">
            <button class="button button-block button-positive upload-btn" ng-click="addImage12()">
                capture
            </button>
        </a>
```

below is my controller

```
.controller('imageController',function($scope,$state,$rootScope,toaster,$translate,$cordovaCamera){    
  $scope.addImage12 = function() {
    var options = {
       quality: 80,
       destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
       sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
       allowEdit: false,
       encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
       targetWidth: 250,
       targetHeight: 250,
       popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
       saveToPhotoAlbum: false
   };

   $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
       $scope.srcImage = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
       console.log($scope.srcImage);
       window.preventDefault();
   }, function(err) {
       console.log(err);
       window.preventDefault();
   });
  };
})
```

Everything seems to be working fine till the capturing the image part .when I click on the tick button after the image capture It is taking me back to the app's first page instead staying in the same page from where the button is clicked.any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did the app loading from first?

Comment: yes it is going to my app js and executing my otherwise condition.But all the values which I entered before are there.So it is not getting refreshed but just starts from the beginning .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is because of closing your app because of opening the native application(camera). May be your app will start from the first if minimized. If it is there, Please solve that issue and try to stay in the current state.

http://tripleneo.nl/resume-app-using-angularjs-ionic/ see this link

After reading that, in your case there should not be any confirm dialogue, Just send the user to the current camera state

Comment: even I thought of the above solution.No other work around available other than this ?

Comment: Basically, app should not be start from the first on minimize and open. If you do that, your work is almost done

Comment: Thanks for the your help.ideally I should use a on resume state to handle things or $state.go in my success handler to be within the page

Comment: I am adding the $state.go because on resume would not work in my case as I have the camera features in 3 pages .So I am adding it in the on sucess method